# Swap method implementation at runtime in .NET?

Tags: .net, mocking, swap

How can i change the implementation of a method at runtime from `return false;` to `return true;`? I don't have control over the methods implementation as it comes with a third-party library. Any workaround is appreciated. Again: I do not control neither the method itself nor it's callers.

Comment: Are you trying to evade the library's licensing code?

Comment: would this be considered, slightly unethical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`MethodRental.SwapMethodBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.methodrental.swapmethodbody.aspx) method.

Comment: how is this method used? du i have to generate binary il myself?

Comment: According to the page you linked it works only for dynamic modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the callers of that method and return true instead calling it. Maybe you can post more details.

Comment: No, he can't.  Read the question

Comment: SLaks, I ment using reflection he could intercept the callers of that method. I have read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information about your problem. If you only want to switch the boolean result a simple `bool result = !MyMethod();` will be enought ;)

Answer (score -1):

A little more info would help. Can you wrap the library and have others call your wrapper? This might be a great TDD avenue too. Are there interfaces involved you can implement yourself? Again, DI could allow you to swap out implementations.

Answer (score -1):

Subclass and override.  If you can't subclass, use a Decorator pattern.

Comment: He can't do either - it's a static method (see first comment to first answer) and he doesn't control the call sites